# Knockout.js – Getting the Object Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, javascript-objects

I just started playing around with knockout and I have a question. Here's part of the code:

```
function Task(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

function ViewModel() {
    self.taskArr = ko.observableArray([
    // some default data
    new Task({ name: "to-do 1"}),
    new Task({ name: "to-do 2"}),
    new Task({ name: "to-do 3"})
]);
```

Basically, I'm trying to display the contents of the object via `console.log()`. But when I use `console.log(self.taskArr());` I get `[Task, Task, Task]` as a result.

Using `self.taskArr()[0].name` will only get the first result, not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display the data of an observable array, you'll have to use the ko.toJSON function, like so:

```
console.log(ko.toJSON(self.taskArr()));
```

which will output:

```
[{"name":"to-do 1"},{"name":"to-do 2"},{"name":"to-do 3"}]
```

More info here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the Task objects to JSON strings:

```
    console.log(JSON.stringify(self.taskArr()));
```

Comment: this works if I create an array manually and then push data into it, but through the Task function it returns blanks, like this: [{},{},{}]

Comment: Like you mention in your answer below, it appears knockout has its own JSON encoder, `ko.toJSON`.